# Different time of the execution CListCtrl::InsertItem on the same amount of records

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I have a CListCtrl with 10000 records that is filled up when the program starts and time of this operation is ~1.3 sec.
But if the user refreshes the list, it fills up in ~2.5 - 3 sec.

In both cases works the same piece of code:

```
SetRedraw(FALSE);
SetItemCount(nCount);

// insert

SetRedraw(TRUE);
```

Variable *nCount* is equal to 0 when the program starts and 10000 when user refreshes the list.

Why does the time of list filling is so different?

**UPD: the minimal code**

```
void CTestList::Init()
{
    InsertColumn(0, _T("Number"),   0, 50);
    InsertColumn(1, _T("Obj name"), 0, 150);
    InsertColumn(2, _T("Creator"),  0, 100);
    InsertColumn(3, _T("Editor"),   0, 100);
}

void CTestList::Reset()
{
    LVITEM item;

    item.iItem = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        InsertRow(item, i);
        item.iItem++;
    }
}

void CTestList::InsertRow(LVITEM& item, int num)
{
    CString strNum;

    //
    item.iSubItem = 0;
    item.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_PARAM;
    item.lParam = NULL;
    item.iImage = 0;

    strNum.Format(_T("%d"), num);
    item.pszText = (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)strNum;
    InsertItem(&item);

    //
    item.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
    item.iSubItem = 1;
    item.pszText = _T("Test object");
    SetItem(&item);

    //
    item.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
    item.iSubItem = 2;
    item.pszText = _T("Any one");
    SetItem(&item);

    // 
    item.iSubItem = 3;
    item.pszText = _T("Another one");
    SetItem(&item);
}

void CApp::FillList()
{
    CWaitCursor wait;

    m_list.DeleteAllItems();

    clock_t begin = clock();
    m_list.SetRedraw(FALSE);    
    m_list.SetItemCount(nCount);
    m_list.Reset();
    m_list.SetRedraw(TRUE);
    clock_t end = clock();

    double dif = static_cast<double>(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    CString str;

    str.Format(_T("Insertion time: %f"), dif);
    AfxMessageBox(str);
}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide a *minimal*, reproducible code sample.

Comment: Depending on the kind of item the list holds it might need to first destroy all the items before pushing the new ones.

Comment: @csl wait a moment, i'll make it

Comment: @RedX yes, that's right. I do DeleteAllItems() before SetRedraw(FALSE), but I didn't wrote it here

Comment: Why aren't you using a [virtual list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ye4z8x58.aspx)?

Comment: I would use spy++ to check if list is not getting some unnecessary messages, also virtual list is a best choice for huge amounts of data.

Comment: @marcinj virtual list is a best choice unless you dont want to sort or filter data in list

Comment: @brightside90 thats not true, you can build virtual list on array of indexes to actual list data, then you only sort indexes of filter them. This is really super fast.

Comment: @marcinj ok, can you provide some example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested your code on my machine. I can reproduce the different timings only if I run the program in the debugger (using <kbd>F5</kbd>), but not if I run it without debugger (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>). So this seems not to be directly related to your code or Windows API but to the debugger.

Comment: I have run this code in debugger and in release and also noticed, that release mode is much more faster, than debugger. But this isn't the solution. In both cases the difference in execution time between first list filling and subsequent is significant.

Comment: @brightside90: I was not talking about debug/release, only about under the debugger and without debugger. On my machine there was no different timing when not running the program without debugger. Maybe there is some other constraint or some other relevant code that you did not post in your question!?

Comment: You are right. That was my omission :( I've tried to run the program only under debug/release mode, and such thought like "How about to run the program without using any modes?" have never been in my head :( Thank you, @Werner Henze  Now I'm getting approximately equal timings every time I run the program and refreshes the list.